# How do I execute a Javascript function requires a value after an onload function is completed that gives the value?

Tags: javascript, ajax, database

I know its a long question, so allow me to explain as best as I can.

I have two javascript functions that I want to run after the page loads, we will call them function1() and function2().

function1() uses AJAX to retrieve information from the database that will arrange the contents in a div from the information obtained in the database.  It also returns the contents from the database once the function has finished.

function2() requires the value from the database in order to run properly, so it needs to wait until function1() returns its value before function2() runs.  Unfortunately my code is not working, and without going into too much detail, below is a schematic of the code:

```
function function1() {
if (some_cookie_exists) {
  //run some code
} else {
  //send parameters through "POST"
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var a = some_value_from_database;
    // change div content
  return a;
  }
  }
//sending parameters
}
function function2(a) {
//run code that depends on value of "a"
}

window.onload = function() {
var data = function1();
function2(data);
```

The error I get is that var data is undefined.  function1() retrieves the data successfully, and runs as I intended it to, but function2() does not execute at all, because the value is missing.  Can anyone figure out why I am getting this and how I should go about solving this?

NOTE: I am really only familiar with Javascript (still novice at that), I know essentially nothing about JQuery, so if you do use this to fix the code, please explain to me why this works (it will save me trouble later)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous (that's what the first A stands for). The results of the AJAX operation are not available in function1(), they're retrieved in the `onreadystatechange` handler that you attach to the XMLHttpRequest object. So it's not clear how you could be doing

```
var a = some_value_from_database;
```

in `function1()`.

What you need to do is call `function2()` from the `onreadystatechange` handler.

If you post the actual implementation of `function1` we may be able to provide more specific details.

UPDATE:

Here's how to call `function2()` when the value becomes available from the AJAX call:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var a = some_value_from_database;
        function2(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly myself, but when I retrieve the value, i get the value from the database.  Like I said, I am relatively new to JavaScript

Comment: I have placed the function above

Comment: Sorry, now its there, so I did attach an onreadystatechange handler

Comment: You're returning the value from the onreadystatechange handler, that's not the same as returning from `function1()`. `function1()` doesn't wait for the AJAX call to complete, it returns right after it sends the request (I assume there's an `xmlhttp.send()` somewhere that you didn't show).

Comment: See edited answer with the code you need to use in the handler.

Comment: Yes, there is an xmlhttp.send() in my code.  I will try this out to see if it works, thanks for the help.  While on the topic, is there a way to do this without embedding function2 into function1?

Comment: It's possible to make synchronous AJAX calls, but it's not a good idea because it locks up the browser until the server answers.

Comment: Good point, actually that gives me an idea.  Your code worked for me, thanks for all your help Barmar, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Do it with a callback.

```
function function1(callback) {
    /* ... */
    callback(data); // instead of return
}
var function2 = function(data) { // important: make "function2" a variable so that it can be passed as an argument later on
    /* ... */
}    
window.onload = function() {
    function1(function2); // important: no parentheses after function2, otherwise it would be executed right away
}
```

Comment: What exactly does callback do?  I remember reading about it somewhere else, but did not understand it

Comment: The concept of a callback means that you don't pass a return value around but rather the function to be executed next.

Answer (score 0):

Because ajax by definition is asynchronous, function2 will start executing before the ajax completes in function1. JQuery would be useful here, as you can place function2 in the success callback of the ajax call in function1.

So include JQuery in your HTML and the following JS should work:

```
$(function() {   //same as onload
      function1() ;
}

function function1() {
        $.ajax({
              url: "url here",
              type: "GET",
               success: function(data) { // data is what is returned in ajax response
                           // rearrange divs
                            function2(data);
                }
           });
);

function function2(data) {
}
```

More on the JQuery ajax function here: 
 http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/